# WebSocket is getting a 404 upon opening connection

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, tomcat, websocket

I am running:

- Tomcat 7
- Java version 1.8
- Chrome browser version 41.0.2272.89 m

I am trying to get my websocket to work, but for some reason I am getting a 404 (In chrome) when trying to access the socket.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/InfiniteCloud/WebSocketExchange' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

The error happens when I try to open the connection. I looked up lots of previous questions from this forum, but non of them worked. Here is my server side code:

```
package websocket;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

@ServerEndpoint( value = "/ClientDataExchange")
public class WebSocketExchange {

    static Set<Session> _users = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen(Session userSession){
        _users.add(userSession);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void handleMessage(String message, Session userSession){
        try{

            if(userSession.getUserProperties().get("username") == null){
                userSession.getUserProperties().put("username", message);
                userSession.getBasicRemote().sendText( newUserJSONResponse(message) );
            }
            System.out.println("Message: " + message);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void handleClose(Session userSession){
        _users.remove(userSession);
    }

    public String newUserJSONResponse(String username){
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
        j.put("ICmessage", "You are now connected as: " + username);

        return j.toJSONString();
    }
}
```

Client side Code:

```
var websocket = null;

function sendMessage(){
    websocket.send("Justin");
}

function testWebSocket(){
    var url = "ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname + "WebSocketExchange";

    websocket = new WebSocket(url);

    websocket.onopen = function(){
        console.log("Connected to: " + url);
    }

    websocket.onmessage = function processMessage(message){

        var jsonData = JSON.parse(message.data);

        if(jsonData.message != null){
            console.log(jsonData.message);
        }else{
            console.log("Empty message...");
        }
    }

    websocket.onclose = function(){
        console.log("Closing connection to: " + url);
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems that your paths do not match. On the server you have @ServerEndpoint( value = "/ClientDataExchange") and on the client you     have var url = "ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname + "WebSocketExchange";

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea how I missed that. Make that an answer so I can give you an answer point! :)

Comment: great! created an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your paths do not match. On the server you have

`@ServerEndpoint( value = "/ClientDataExchange")`

And on the client you have

```
var url = "ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname + "WebSocketExchange";
```